# Returning a value or Cancel from Excel userform

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a sub that calls a userform to show and would only like to proceed if the user didn't click my Cancel button. I don't want to put all my other sub calls within the userform.

Is it possible to have a userform return a value or a way to check if the user clicked a particular button?

I suppose I can use a global variable, but was wondering if I could pass things to and from a userform.

Comment: I would go with the global variable myself. There are other ways to do it but that will work.

Comment: From the UserForm are you calling a subroutine elsewhere (like in a separate module) that handles user input?  You can pass `UserFom1.ActiveControl.Name` to that function and use a `CASE` statement based on the name of the control.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to use properties.

Inside your userForm

```
Private m_bCancel As Boolean

Public Property Get Cancel() As Boolean
    Cancel = m_bCancel
End Property

Public Property Let Cancel(ByVal bCancel As Boolean)
    m_bCancel = bCancel
End Property
```

Code for the cancel button

```
Private Sub cmdCancel_Click()
    Me.Cancel=True
    Me.Hide
End Sub
```

Call the userForm from outside like this

```
sub loadForm()

dim frm 

set frm= new UserForm1
frm.show

if frm.Cancel then
   Msgbox "Cancelled"
end if

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried this and got an "Out of stack space" error.  It keeps looping through the Let Cancel property.