# VBA Search without msgBox but with a Userform instead

Tags: vba, excel

would this code be possible with a custom userform instead the msgbox? since it's not possible to edit a msgbox with custom buttons. I would like to continue on the loop after the msgbox desicion. I know with vba it's not possible but is there a way around?
The code:

```
Sub Forward()

    StrVal = UserForm1.TextBox3.Text
    If Trim(UserForm1.TextBox3.Text) = "" Then Exit Sub

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        fstAddress = ""
        With ws
            Set Loc = .Cells.Find(what:=StrVal, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
            If Not Loc Is Nothing Then
                Do
                    fstAddress = fstAddress & "|" & Loc.Address

                    Loc.Parent.Activate 'Activate the correct sheet.
                    Loc.Activate        'and then the cell on the sheet.

                    bDecision = MsgBox("Weitersuchen?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Replace or Select value?")

                    If bDecision = vbYes Then
                        Set Loc = .Cells.FindNext(Loc)
                    End If

                    If Loc Is Nothing Then Exit Do
                Loop While InStr(fstAddress, Loc.Address) = 0
            End If
        End With
    Next ws

End Sub
```

would this work?:
http://shutupdean.com/blog/2014/08/01/vba-msgbox-custom-button-text/

Comment: what do you exactly want to do?

Comment: Perhaps the solution at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51245196/vba-userform-as-inputbox/51246398#51246398 may help you finding your own solution

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32190506/4996248

Comment: I think you need to review the help for the `Find` function.  You are not using it like the example suggests (it would be better).  I'd also like to object to your statement that "with VBA it's not possible", perhaps you just need to be enlightened on how to use VBA properly.  Maybe you should look into the how to show the form using a `vbModeless` state

Comment: @cesc: it **is possible** with VBA, just build a custom userform

Comment: `Loop While InStr(fstAddress, Loc.Address) = 0` will fail with (eg) A1, A10

Comment: all right one after another. @DisplayName I want to search for strings and skip to the next one in a workbook. like searching for strings on a browser with ctrl + F. **Guest** I don't want a msgBox...
**John Coleman** I tried something similar already, but I need the code to continue from where it breaks in the loop. Debug the code and you'll see what I mean.
**Profex** I think we're talking at cross purposes. 
**Our Man in Bananas** I tried that already but unfortunately a userform doesn't continue after a break.
**Tim Williams** changed it.